# Is it possible to find the filepath of a font used in an MAC OSX App

Tags: macos, cocoa, fonts

I am using a `Label NSTextField` in my App.

I changed the font to say Arial 
In my App i want to know the path of the Font

**For Example :**

```
/Volumes/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
```

Is it possible to find the path of the Font i used ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)getFontPathOfFont:(NSFont *)font
{

    CTFontDescriptorRef fontRef = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithNameAndSize ((CFStringRef)[font fontName], [font pointSize]);
    CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)CTFontDescriptorCopyAttribute(fontRef, kCTFontURLAttribute);
    NSString *fontPath = [NSString stringWithString:[(NSURL *)CFBridgingRelease(url) path]];
    return fontPath;
}
```

The above code solved my question - i just have to send the font

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSString *)getFontPath : (NSString *)fontName
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *libraryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);
        NSString *fontPath = nil;
        for (NSString *path in libraryPaths) {
           NSString *currentFontPath = [[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Fonts"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fontName];
            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:currentFontPath]) {
                fontPath = currentFontPath;
                break;
            }
        }
        return fontPath;
    }
}

[AppDelegate getFontPath:@"Arial.ttf"];
 output :  /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
```

Comment: In this solution i have to attach .ttf or .otf at the end. I just want to send the font family name such as

Arial or Helvetica or Georgia

For example

    NSFont *f = [myTF font];
    [AppDelegate getFontPath:f.familyName];